# To become a Project Manager, what coursework should be taken?

Tags: career, education

I am currently looking to move from dominantly presales and delivery work into more of a project management role.

What coursework is most helpful in setting oneself up for success as a PM?

Specifically, what degree program type would be most helpful (MBA, IE, HR, etc)?

Comment: and the downvote is for ...?

Comment: Not *exactly* the same question, but may offer some helpful points of view (or may not!) http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-does-someone-get-into-project-management

Comment: I think this is (arguably) outside the scope of PM:SE.

Comment: Your question is currently too broad, and likely to be un-generalizable to anyone but you. Please describe what you've looked into, provide some detailed context, and then ask specific questions about any details that remain unclear about your specific situation.

Comment: @CodeGnome - that's just it: I don't know what I don't know, and am trying to find out. If PM.SE isn't a place to answer questions about how to become/prep for being a PM from an educational perspective, what would be better?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - how would you propose scoping this better? As I mentioned last week to CodeGnome, I don't know what I don't know ... so also don't know how to better ask this question yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would recommend Prince2, PMP, and Agile courses if you're looking to study - professional courses teach you a great deal about project management and don't take as long/are not as expensive as degree/masters courses.

Having said that, project management is less about process and more about people and communication skills - you don't need coursework/a degree for that.

From personal experience, I would recommend (assuming you're already working in a field you want to stay in), take a prince/agile course, and try and get experience as an assistant PM/PMO etc..you will already have the product knowledge for your business area, and you can start to build up the other skills you need to do a PM role.

Good luck!